# Catch text using a regex with specific rules

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

Ok, I'm trying to catch text using a regex with the following rules:

- Each new line starts with the word `type` or `tag`, and `:` comes after that. | `type` or `tag` should be the capture group 1
- A varchar might come after `:` | That varchar should be the capture group 2
- `\\` comes after that
- A number comes after `\\` | That number should be the capture group 3
- `?` might come after the number
- If we have `?`, a varchar might come after `?` | That varchar should be the capture group 4
- If we have `?` + a varchar, then `:` might come after that
- If we have `?`+ a varchar + `:`, then a varchar might come after that | That varchar should be the capture group 5

Examples:

```
type:test\\1?value12:value9        // Should get: Group 1 = type, Group 2 = test, Group 3 = 1, Group 4 = value12, Group 5 = value9

type:\\22?value62:value3        // Should get: Group 1 = type, Group 2 = NULL, Group 3 = 22, Group 4 = value62, Group 5 = value3
```

My regex is:

```
/(type|tag):([^\\]+)?\\\\([0-9]{1,3})?\??([^\:]+):([^\:]+)?/i
```

I believe that it's not accurate, for example:

```
type:\\1p?hello:iii
```

The current regex matches `1` as Group 3 and `p?hello` as Group 4, however, it should not match this at all. Group 3 must be number and `?` might come after it, `type:\\1p?hello:iii` doesn't follow the format that we want.

Anyone can help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/(type|tag):(\w+)?\\\\([0-9]{1,3})?\??(\w+)?:?(\w+)?/gi
```

Tested [here](https://regexr.com/66ban) and php [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f490fbf9d2c9247958bf360309a8779b0a4c183)

I think it's better to match word `\w` instead of just avoiding matching others characters

Comment: Sorry, looks like you were trying to test your solution while I was editing the question.

Comment: I guess it does not works? can you give more examples? like `type:\\1p?hello:iii` the `1p` will not always be a number, it can be only a number or a number and one or more characters?

Comment: What it comes after `?` can be only a number. `\w` used for words, but it should match varchar (it can be a varchar) instead of words. Thanks.

Comment: what is varchar? `\w` match alphanumeric and underscore

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
/^(type|tag):([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\\\([0-9]{1,3})(?:\?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?::([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?)?$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Isa8xa/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(type|tag)` - `type` or `tag`
- `:` - a colon
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]*)` - Group 2: zero or more alphanumeric chars
- `\\\\` - two backslashes
- `([0-9]{1,3})` - Group 3: one, two or three digits
- `(?:\?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?::([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\?` - a `?` char
  - `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` - Group 4: one or more alphanumeric chars
  - `(?::([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?` - an optional sequence of

    - `:` - a colon
    - `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` - Group 5: one or more alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.